# SendGrid can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am getting an error, where I get a promise rejection:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Should I not be returning JSON after the email is sent, or what is the best way to fix this to allow me to send multiple emails from the page.

```
import * as httpStatus from 'http-status';
import config from '../config/config';

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

function sendemail(req, res) {
  sgMail.setApiKey(config.sendgridKey);

  const msg = {
    to: req.body.to,
    from: req.body.from,
    subject: req.body.subject,
    text: req.body.content,
    html: '<strong>' + req.body.content + '</strong>',
  };

  sgMail.send(msg).then(result => {
    return res.sendStatus(httpStatus.OK).json({ success: true });
  }, err => {
    return res.sendStatus(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ success: false });
  });
}

export default {
  sendemail
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `res.sendStatus` and after to use `res.json`.

```
res.sendStatus(xxx).json(xxx) => dont use
```

You need use `res.status(xxx).json(xxx)`